# Русское слово «оди́н» и немецкое «О́дин»

Tags: этимология

Известное в русском языке слово, *числительное **оди́н***, имеет в немецком языке внешне точно такое же слово ***О́дин*** (др.-сканд. *Óðinn*), но в значении Божества (О́дин — верховный Бог, германо-скандинавский пантеон).

Интересно, что в словаре Фасмера статьи про **бога О́дина** мы не нашли.
В статье же про русское числительное **оди́н** ссылок на русско-(пра-)немецкие параллели тоже нет. Из наиболее близкого указано только готское *AINS* в значении "один".

Вопрос: может ли русское **оди́н** иметь какое-то отношение к немецкому **О́дин**?

Answer (score 1):

Не может.

Русское Один - фонетически измененное праславянское (если не индоевропейское) или индоевропейское  *edinъ. 
Заимcтвование для этой цели имени "непойми какого" бога у народа, появившегося по меньшей мере тысячелетие спустя, невозможно в принципе.

Comment: Так это вам невозможно.
А на латыни  ячмень - ORDEUM,  ордынский из орды, в английском - barley, от "медведей".  А в датском вообще топоним явный - byg, и пивасик и место где распивают - beer, bar. Без всяких "реконструкций", корешок на тысячи слов разошелся с интересным синонимом при переводе, медведь - "неси".
Так и С  Одином,  одно-глазым.

Comment: Бегемотусу:
Из и.-е. *edinъ и произошло "современное" ОДиН.
К тому же, нам хорошо известно, что сканд. ОДИН - своего рода ровесник "древнерусского языка". 

Если русское ОДиН произошло из EDIN, значит и сканд. ОДИН, скорее всего, произошло из русского же.

К тому нет никаких препятствий.

Comment: Не нужно быть таким категоричным: wednesday - это день Одина, как видно тут тоже есть корень "едн".

Comment: @DmitryOvchinnikov -  поподробнее пожалуйста. Какое отношение день недели имеет к русскому слову Один? И главное - как ваше мнение может опровергнуть написанное мною?

Answer (score 1):

А на латыни  ячмень - ORDEUM,  ордынский из орды, в английском - barley, от "медведей".  А в датском вообще топоним явный - byg, и пивасик и место, где распивают, - beer, bar. Без всяких "реконструкций" корешок на тысячи слов разошелся с интересным синонимом при переводе, медведь - "неси", и стойким, как оловянный солдатик, очень историческим прозвищем "русские медведи".
Вот bir переводится во всех тюркских как один, (бир сум, бир таньга, бир рубль), что - Один, Единица. А соответствует русскому бирюк (берюк) - одинокий, медведь шатун, злой и угрюмый.  В переводе на английский бирюк - MOROZE.
Так и С  Одином,  одноглазым.

[image]

[image]

Там, на западе, даже с точностью не знали, на какой глаз кривой, этот Один с русским кривым ножиком булатным.
А официальная лингвистика от польского, а не в. ст. нем.,  где предлагаемое ими Wōđinaz -звучит - води нас.
А проще говоря, один такой -води князь. Русский мужичок, которого богом и прозвали.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что эти два слова имеют один и тот же корень, учитывая также исторические связи Славян и Варягов.
Я также думаю, что русское и германо-викингское слово «Один» и греческое слово «Афина» произошли от слова «Атон / Aten», который был объявлен единственным богом IV Аменхотепом в Египте в 14 веке до нашей эры.
По этой причине очень противоречиво то, что и викинги, и русские раньше были политеистами / язычниками.

Answer (score -1):

Слово "один" обрело своё начертание при Петре 1 или его батюшке Алексее (первая половина 18-го века), до этого писалось един. Древнескандинавский, согласно вики, почил в Средневековье и не дотянул до Нового времени (15-век)

Comment: Не хотел бы брать шефство надолго, поэтому постарайтесь собственноручно править Ваши тексты. Не хотелось бы проставлять точки, вычищать чёрточки оттуда, где их никогда не бывает, и менять арабские цифры на традиционные, римские.

Comment: вот тут, пожалуйста, поподробнее (римские цифры, на мой взгляд, это уже перебор; взгляните на заголовок первого попавшегося сайта - https://histrf.ru/lenta-vremeni/century-1800) Это же не написание работы на соискание учёной степени? С пунктуацией вроде всё норм.

Comment: Примерно так отписывают те, кому ТАКУДОБНЕЕ, пишут по типу смс другу. Вы и здесь — со строчной, без точки. Вобщем всё норм.

Comment: Уже поздняк метаться, редактирование запрещено. Но если исходить из Вашей логики, то название отдельных табов "текущие", "по дате публикации" и "голос" такожде следовало бы писать с заглавной; тожде самое следовало бы распространить и на название метки "этимология"